# Regular Expression with start of string (^) cannot match Array.toString() in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am doing a regular expression check on the pattern `function Object() {}` and I use the statement

`Array.toString().match(/^function\s+([^\(]+)/)`

This statement works in modern browsers and returns `["function Array", "Array"]`

But in Internet Explorer 8, the above statement always return `null`. After some try and error I found that the problem occurs at the `^` symbol. When I remove it to `Array.toString().match(/function\s+([^\(]+)/)`, the result becomes correct.

But the latter regular expression is not logically correct because it does not guarantee the `function` keyword starts from the beginning, thus possible giving some false positive.

I would like to know is there work around or I have missed something? Thank you.

**Update:**

After @nicael suggestion, I test a bunch of regular expressions and found an interesting result

`Correct` means it returns `["function Array", "Array"]`

1. Matching the string instead of `Array.toString()` -> **Correct**

'`function Array() { [native code] } '.match(/^function\s+([^\(]+)/)`

2. Replace `^` with `.{1,10}` -> `null`

`Array.toString().match(/.{1,10}function\s+([^\(]+)/)`

3. Replace `^` with `.+` -> `null`

`Array.toString().match(/.+function\s+([^\(]+)/)`

4. **Replace `^` with `.{0}`** -> **Correct**

`Array.toString().match(/.{0}function\s+([^\(]+)/)`

The most interesting result is that with `.{0}`, it works. But it is actually matching nothing. I am thinking if the `Array.toString()` actually outputs something before the `function...` string but using `document.write()` cannot show it but still it does not explain how `.{0}` and `^` differs (only in IE8)

**Final Update:**

It turns out that the problem is that `Array.toString` does not return the function string in one-line but multiple lines. So the correct regular expression to work across browsers will be
`Array.toString().match(/[\r\n]?function\s+([^\(]+)/)`

Comment: At least you could have tried to output your string to match first, and see the problem.

Comment: @nicael Yes I actually output the string in both Chrome and IE8, and they are the same, which is why I struggle because the string is equal and so I expect the regex to work in both browsers. I have updated the question for reference

Comment: Does the ^ fails anytime on IE? Have you tried checking other generic cases? What about any expression with $ (end of the string)?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any space or something at the beginning? Try `Array.toString().search(/function\s+([^\(]+)/)`

Comment: @nicael Thanks, I follow your suggestion, and test a bunch of regular expression. It turns out that `^` is not broken (at least not in other examples), and I have updated my question to give the result I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type `Array.toString()` in IE8 console, you can see that the output **is not** the string

```
`function Array() { [native code] }`
```

Instead, the output is

```
`
function Array() {
    [native code]
}
`
```

That is, there is a newline before `function`. That's why your regex doesn't match.

Comment: To get cross-browsers working, the regular expression has to be changed to `/[\r\n]?function\s+([^\(]+)/`